# I'm having trouble comparing the characters in my character array

Tags: c++, char

I am making a minesweeper type program for my c++ class where I read a file like this

```
4 4
*...
....
.*..
....
3 5
**...
.....
.*...
0 0
```

and then output a file like this

```
Field #1:
*100
2210
1*10
1110

Field #2:
**100
33200
1*100
```

I figured I'd start out by reading the contents of the grid in the input file into a 2-d character array, except I would replace the periods with zeros. Then hopefully later I could do some math on the character array (not sure if that works well. I'm new to c++).

Anyways, I'm trying to check whether a character is an asterisk but that condition always returns false even if the character is an asterisk. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream mineData;
    mineData.open("input_mine_data.txt");
    int numRows = 0;
    int numColumns = 0;

    mineData >> numRows;
    mineData >> numColumns;

    cout << numRows;
    cout << numColumns;
    cout << "\n\n";

    char Grid[50][50];


    for (int iRows = 0; iRows < numRows; iRows++)
    {
        for (int iCols = 0; iCols < numColumns; iCols++)
        {
            //if current character is an asterisk
            if (Grid[iRows][iCols] == '*')
            {
                //put the asterisk in the Grid array
                mineData >> Grid[iRows][iCols];
            }

            //if the current character is a period, put a zero
            //in the grid array instead
            else
            {
                Grid[iRows][iCols] = '0';
            }

        }
    }

    for (int iRows = 0; iRows < numRows; iRows++)
    {
        for (int iCols = 0; iCols < numColumns; iCols++)
        {
            cout << Grid[iRows][iCols];

        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: where do you read your file into Grid array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Grid` unitialized here:

```
if (Grid[iRows][iCols] == '*')
```

this needs to be moved before the *if* check:

```
mineData >> Grid[iRows][iCols];
```

and then you can just check if it is *not* an `*` and set it to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Grid` is empty. You have initialized `Grid` but have not read any data into it, so checking whether there will be an asterisk in `Grid` will definitely return `false`.
Instead of:

```
if (Grid[iRows][iCols] == '*') //Empty array will return false
```

Do this:

```
char tmp;
if (mineData >> tmp == '*')...
```